# Why is this.props undefined when I'm passing in actions to mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**tl;dr:** In the LoginForm, `this.props` is undefined despite my passing in actions in mapDispatchToProps.

I've set breakpoints in the `connect` function, and the action is making it into the connect function, but for whatever reason, in the `handleSubmit` function, this.props is undefined.

I'm stumped.

I have a separate 'SignUp' flow that's basically identical to what I have below, and it works perfectly.

I essentially copy pasted the sign up code, and renamed everything "login", and modified things slightly and for whatever reason **this.props is undefined, even though what I'm passing into mapDispatchToProps seems to be correct.**

The component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { loginSubmit, loginUpdateField } from '../../redux/actions/login.actions';
import { TextInput } from '../../stories/TextInput';
import { Button } from '../../stories/Button';

export class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Props: ', this.props); // UNDEFINED!!!!!!
  }

  handleUpdateField(field, value) {
    // this.props.updateField(field, value);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form style={{ 'WebkitPerspective': '1000' }}>
        <TextInput label="Username" id="username" /> <br />
        <TextInput label="Password" id="password" type="password" /> <br /><br />

        <Button disabled={false} primary size="medium" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} label="Ready for Takeoff" />
        <Button disabled={false} size="medium" onClick={() => alert} label="Cancel" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { loginSubmit, loginUpdateField }
)(LoginForm);
```

The action:

```
export const loginSubmit = (fieldValues) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loginSubmitBegin);

    let errors = isFormValid(fieldValues);

    if (!errors.formValid) {
      dispatch(loginErrors(errors));
    } else {
      axios
        .post(`https://api.mydomain.io/login`, fieldValues, { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", } })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch(loginSuccess({ username: 'testuser' }));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          handleErr(err.response.data.error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

The reducers:

```
const initialState = {
  loginStatus: 'not_started',
  fieldValues: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  },
  errors: {
    formValid: false,
    username: [],
    password: [],
  }
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_UPDATE_FIELD':
      let newState = {
        ...state,
      };
      newState.fieldValues[action.payload.fieldName] = action.payload.fieldValue;

      return newState;

    case 'LOGIN_SUBMIT_BEGIN':
      return {
        ...state,
        signupStatus: 'pending'
      };

    case 'LOGIN_ERRORS':
      return {
        ...state,
        signupStatus: 'errors',
        errors: action.payload
      };

    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        signupStatus: 'success'
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Combined Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import signup from './signup.reducers';
import user from './user.reducers';
import login from './login.reducers';

export default combineReducers({ login, user, signup});
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { LoginForm } from '../features/LoginForm';
import './signup.css';

export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <article>
      <section>
        <h2>Login!!</h2> <br /> <br />
        <LoginForm />
      </section>
    </article>
  );
};

LoginPage.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape({})
};

LoginPage.defaultProps = {
  user: null,
};
```

Comment: Where do you import `LoginForm`? If you're importing the named export by accident, you won't be connected to the store

Comment: Is `this` the component inside handleSubmit? Seems like it should be, given that you’re calling bind; but my guess is that _this_ is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Nick I updated my question to show where I'm importing LoginForm.

Comment: @rayhatfield I thought that might be the case too, but upon double checking `this` appears to be what it should be: The LoginForm component.

Comment: @Nick That was the problem!! Please submit an answer so I can accept it, and give you credit. Also, I don't understand why that's a problem. Would you mind explaining further?

Comment: Weird. I wouldn’t have expected props to be undefined even if you’re importing the non-connected version. It’s still a component. Humph.

Comment: @TylerBiscoe the named export is just your regular component. The default export is at the bottom where you `export default connect(...)(LoginForm)`. That default export is the component you want because it has your actions mapped in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the named export from this component, then you're importing the unconnected component:

```js
import { LoginForm } from "./LoginForm";
```

Since the redux-connected component is the *default* export, you have to make sure to import the default export if you want it to be the redux-connected version.

```js
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
```

One way to avoid this mistake in the future is to not even export the unconnected `LoginForm` component. In other words, you can just declare the class as `class LoginForm extends React.Component { ... }` rather than `export class LoginForm extends React.Component { ... }`.